Flutter Best way to create form with a button on the bottom?
Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
On a smaller device, where all the input fields can't be  displayed on a single page, the form should be like this:

But on a bigger screen, where all the Input fields
can be displayed on one page, I want it to be like this:

(Notice the spacing between the button and the last input
field should be dynamic, so that even on tablets the button will be on the bottom of the screen)
Please before providing an answer also check how it reacts to the keyboard being opened, I don't want it to make the button move upwards... like this:

Also, of course, I don't want the keyboard to cause overflows, or make the input fields not accessible, I have tried many things, and I haven't found a way to achieve it, even though it seems to be a simple problem.

I am using a LayoutBuilder, SingleChildScrollView and ConstrainedBox to give the min height to the Column.
To place the button at the bottom when there are enough room, use a Spacer, and using a Spacer inside SingleChildScrollView would also need to warp the Column with an IntrinsicHeight.
This approach is demonstrated in the documentation of SingleChildScrollView.
To avoid the keyboard pushing the button, we need to get the viewInsets using MediaQuery.viewInsetsOf(context) and adjust it to give the min height to the Column.

class A extends StatefulWidget {
  const A({super.key});

  @override
  State<A> createState() => _AState();
}

class _AState extends State<A> {
  int _number = 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final viewInsets = MediaQuery.viewInsetsOf(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            final minHeight = constraints.maxHeight + viewInsets.bottom;
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: minHeight),
                child: IntrinsicHeight(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      Card(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Text('ViewInsets: $viewInsets'),
                            Text('Constraints: $constraints'),
                            Text('minHeight: $minHeight'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      for (var i = 0; i < _number; i++)
                        const Card(
                          child: TextField(),
                        ),
                      // This is for demo only, we could simply use a spacer here
                      const Expanded(
                        child: DecoratedBox(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.fromBorderSide(BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      DecoratedBox(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.fromBorderSide(BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: [
                            IconButton.filled(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  _number++;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                            IconButton.filled(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  _number--;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


That's really good! How did you even thought of this.

Try the following code:
Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Field 1',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      
                      )
                    )
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Field 2',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      
                      )
                    )
                  ),TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Field 3',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      
                      )
                    )
                  ),TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Field 4',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      
                      )
                    )
                  ),TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Field 5',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      
                      )
                    )
                  ),
                         Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: FilledButton(
                onPressed: (){},
                child: Text('Submit'),
              ),
            ),
        )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        
      )

After that, you can make the keyboard push the content as following:
In your Scaffold, set resizeToAvoidBottomInset property to true.


That's not the behavior I'm expecting. In your code the submit button is always on the screen. Look at the first image I provided; I want the button to be visible when scrolling on the bottom.

@MariosPlenchidis , ok i just noticed it, you can move that button to the column of the scroll view, look at the code again.

You can wrap your code with SingleChildScrollView widget that will allow you to scroll to the bottom without overflow and UI will be responsive.
For more details checkout: this
